# cron job setting for a project - how i giv path

Tags: cron

In my project i want to implement a cron job. My con job code is in www.myproject.com/testfolder/cgi-bin/crontest.pm

then what 's the path. that i have to be given in command box. Please replay ..

Answer (score 0):

You have to give a relative or absolute path based on your system file hierarchy. If your web content folder is /var/www/ (default on most linux / apache servers).
If you don't know it, you may `echo __DIR__;` to know the full path of the current directory. Then you canonicalize your cron job's file path based on the current directory.

For exemple if www.myproject.com points to /var/www then your file crontest.pm is at `/var/www/testfolder/cgi-bin/crontest.pm`

NB : be aware that cgi-bin folders are often placed elsewhere on your system, so place the `echo __DIR__;` in this directory or try to know where this alias points to.